# Como detectar si una variable cambia de valor

Tags: java, while

Quisiera mejorar mi codigo que detecta el cambio de valor de la variable 'row' ,y 'RowAnt' que suplanta el anterior resultado de 'row'.Les explico a continuación

```
public class autoListado extends Thread {

frmListaProductosCocina p;
Timer timer = new Timer();
int row = 0;
int rowAnt = 0;


public autoListado(frmListaProductosCocina Jframe) {
    p = Jframe;

    TimerTask listado = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                Statement st = coneccionCC.cn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT count(*) "
                        + "from pedidos where original=0 and activo = 1 ;");
                while (rs.next()) {
                    row = rs.getInt(1);
                }
```

Si  cambia de valor por la consulta 'select' ejecuta cargarInformacion() a un JTable; Saludos

```
  if (rowAnt != row) {//Si el valor es diferente:pass
                    cargarInformacion();
                    rowAnt = row;//Reemplaza al valor que cambio
                } else {
                    rowAnt = row;//El valor sigue igual
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
            }

        }

    };

    timer.schedule(listado, 1000, 1000);
}
```

}

Comment: Cuidado con `Thread.sleep()` porque al detener la ejecución podrías impedir que ocurran otros eventos en el momento adecuado, considera usar [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) ó alguna implementación de [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). No es necesario el `while(rs.nets())`, ya que en dado caso regresará sólo un registro.

Comment: No entiendo ni a que cambio de valor te referis, ni donde lo queres detectar...